# Не вижу разницы между объектами

Tags: java

Создал два объекта fileOne и fileTwo. Оба читают из файла, оба имеют одинаковые методы. В чем между ними разница и какой предпочтительнее использовать для чтения из файла? Благодарю.

```
BufferedReader fileOne = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                        new FileInputStream(reader.readLine())));

System.out.println(fileOne.readLine());
fileOne.close();


BufferedReader fileTwo = new BufferedReader(new 
                FileReader(reader.readLine()));

System.out.println(fileTwo.readLine());
fileTwo.close();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если вы откроете исходный код класса `FileReader` и посмотрите его, достаточно даже строки объявления класса и первого конструктора, то поймете, что это просто обертка для первой вашей конструкции. `FileReader` - наследник `InputStreamReader`, а в конструкторе он создает тот же `FileInputStream`.
Собственно, вот исходный код `FileReader`:

```
public class FileReader extends InputStreamReader {

    public FileReader(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
        super(new FileInputStream(fileName));
    }

    public FileReader(File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
        super(new FileInputStream(file));
    }

    public FileReader(FileDescriptor fd) {
        super(new FileInputStream(fd));
    }

}
```

Рекомендую почаще заглядывать в исходный код используемых классов, так можно много полезного узнать.

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем ответ на вопрос, но позвольте предложить Вам "более современный" подход чтения файлов из пакета NIO 2:

```
Path path = Paths.get("file.txt");
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path);
```

Использую его всегда. (8-я джава)

Comment: Да, об этом уже наслышал. Хочу разобраться в основах. Скорее всего Path работает на базе того, что было создано в более старых версиях Java SDK

Comment: В конкретно этих основах ничего интересного нет. Там просто кучка декораторов, позволяющих вкладывать один ридер в другой, и пара оберток, одну из которых показал @iksuy